# MySql database connection compress

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

How do i compress these two following database connection codes into one code?

**Code1**

```
<?Php
define($base_url = 'http://example.com/url/'); // Change this to your site URL and Path
define($from_email = 'example@email.com'); // Change this email id to your id
///////// Database Details change here  ////
define($dbhost_name = 'mysql.host.com');
define($database = 'databasename123');
define($username = 'username123');
define($password = 'password123');
//////// Do not Edit below /////////
try {
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```

**Code2**

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.host.com');
define('DB_NAME', 'databasename123');
define('DB_USER','username123');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password123');
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(header('Location: ./admin/install.php'));
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die(header('Location: ./admin/install.php'));
?>
```

If there is no possibilities, what is the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you on beforehand

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What you've got here is a bunch of code that spews out variables. You might want to organize this better, like into a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) that provides methods to give you properly configured handles to your database.

Comment: You need to give a little context here. Ok, you are trying to write a Code 3, that does what both Code 1 and Code 2 do. But what are your reasons to combine them? What are the restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

One of your snippets uses PDO and the other uses mysql_connect. Combining them completely is non-trivial, however you could put your database host, name, username and password as variables in another file and then include that file in both the bits of code you have provided. That would at least mean you could update all the database details in one place.